# unable to share image using intent - URI null

Tags: java, android, android-intent, github

Im using a grid view to represent all the images/photos, after the user selection ImageView activity is executed and then the following code is to share that selected image.
Im getting bit confuse i think im missing something hence URI is showing null value.
[here](https://github.com/grilledPhoenix/DesiMeme) is the whole code if necessary!!

```
public class Full_image extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    ImageAdapt imageAdapter = new ImageAdapt(this);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_share) {
        return true;
    }

    // Handle item selection
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); //file to be saved as per user selection
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String fileName = "test.png"; //saved as png file
    File dest = new File(sd, fileName);
    try {
        FileOutputStream out;
        out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_share:
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(dest);
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            shareIntent.setType("image/png");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.action_share))); //shared via Intent
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will work for you, test file you are creating doesn't have write permission we need to tell explicitly to make it writable rest is same.

package com.desimeme.jai.desimeme;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Full_image extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapt imageAdapter = new ImageAdapt(this);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
//        if (id == R.id.action_share) {
//            return true;
//        }
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_share:
                // Handle item selection
                ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); //file to be saved as per user selection
                if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
                    String sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                    File ssd = new File(sd, "share");
                    if (!ssd.exists())
                        ssd.mkdirs();
                    String fileName = "test"; //saved as png file
                    File dest = new File(ssd, fileName + ".png");
                    FileOutputStream out = null;
                    if (dest.canWrite()) {
                        dest.setWritable(true);
                    }
                        try {
                            out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
                            // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            try {
                                if (out != null) {
                                    out.close();
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(dest);
                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.setType("*/*");
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.action_share))); //shared via Intent
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If are trying to share via gmail Email client then you need to write file provider and share file via content stream